# Background-image in CSS

Tags: css, image, background

I have tried following both ways but always getting failed to load image. Tell me what's wrong in this code

```
header{
background-image: url("intro5.jpg");
background-image: url('intro5.jpg');
}
```

Comment: where is your HTML?, header has height?

Comment: Does it fails as a "Not found"? Can you paste the error from console?

Comment: Either your path is incorrect or the element where it is applied has zero height.

Comment: Can you provide enough code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
header{
    background-image: url("correctpathtoimage/intro5.jpg");
    background-image: url('correctpathtoimage/intro5.jpg');
}
```

whats the path/position of the images folder relative to the style sheet folder?

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give proper path of image as below,

```
header{

background-image: url("path_name/intro5.jpg");
background-image: url('path_name/intro5.jpg');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

so let say that structure of your page looks like this

```
/images
    intro5.jpg
    someotherimage1.jpg
    someotherimage2.jpg
    etc...
/js
/css
    style.css
index.html
```

your index.html file is in main folder. if you load styles from file in CSS folder then the path to your image should look like this:

```
background-image: url('../images/intro5.jpg');
```

if you load styles INLINE inside index.html then the path should be

```
background-image: url('images/intro5.jpg');
```

second of all it depends to what are you attaching the `background-image` ?

if it is an anchor `<a>` then you need to add `display: block;` below the `background-image` because some of the elements are inline and inline elements can't have a set width or height